# Set 'host' as default network for Docker

Tags: docker

Docker can build containers just fine up until I connect my Cisco VPN. After that, containers are unable to connect to the outside internet. It's more than a DNS problem, it simply can't route to anything outside of Docker's own network. Now, I can get around this by running containers with `--net=host` But the problem is with building containers with dockerfiles. I see no way to set the host there. Is there somewhere else I can configure docker to simply always use 'host' as the default network?

Comment: exuse me, have you found other solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`docker build` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options) also has a `--network` parameter that you can use to specify the network mode that should be used for intermediate containers. This flag has the same effect and possible values as the [identically named parameter of the `docker run` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings).

> `--network (=default)` Set the networking mode for the `RUN` instructions during build

This should allow you to build your containers with:

```
docker build -t yourimagename --network=host .
```

Comment: That does seem to do the trick. Is there anyway to configure this globally? Or is passing it as an argument the only way?

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no way to configure this globally. I'm not completely sure about that, though.

Comment: The docker build page lists the --network option but is silent about the valid values and their effects @helmbert would you please extend this answer?

Comment: @chrisinmtown The --network option is functionally identical to the corresponding option of `docker run`. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Dockerfile is to define how to *build* an image. It has no runtime parameters beyond setting the default command and/or entrypoint.

Networking is a runtime concern only. If using arguments to `docker run` is not fitting, perhaps you can use docker-compose.yml and either the docker-compose tool, or a swarm. In both cases, you can define network parameters for the container(s) defined in docker-compose.yml.

```yaml
network_mode: "host"
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networkmode).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem on a vm running `CentOS 7`. After I upgraded some yum packages (`containerd,` `container-selinux,` `docker-ce` and `docker-ce-cli`), it was resolved.