# Docker container doesn't have networking without `--network host`

Tags: docker, networking

I'm using Docker 19.03.12 on CentOS 7 and I've noticed that a container doesn't have network access to the outside world unless I use the `--network host` option when I start the container.  Is there a way to configure Docker to automatically use that as a default when I start a container?

Comment: Probably no, since that could be super risky. You could always use `docker-compose` and manage that + your other configuration options with it.

Comment: See also this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681603/set-host-as-default-network-for-docker

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set 'host' as default network for Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681603/set-host-as-default-network-for-docker)

Comment: I would definitely try to find why networking doesn't work; could be an issue with iptables and/or firewalld setting conflicting rules with docker. You can start your daemon with debug mode enabled (set `{"debug":true}` in a `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file, and restart docker. Then check the docker daemon logs if something stands out.

Comment: Running in `--network=host` means that there's no networking isolation for the container. The container won't get its own networking namespace, doesn't get its own IP-address, etc, so not recommended, unless for specific reasons